# AngularJS not sending Authorization or any extra key/value header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, jwt

I am working with JWT tokens with Nodejs And Angular JS. I found $httpProvider way of setting header on each request. But the headers are not being sent. My NodeJS app get undefined on accessing that header.

My angular code

> For setting authorization token -

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', '$localStorage', function($q, $location, $localStorage) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                if ($localStorage.token){
                    console.log($localStorage.token)

                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token;
                    console.log(config.headers);
                }
                return config;
            },
            'responseError': function(response) {
                if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                    $location.path('#login');
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
}]);
```

Here is my HTTP Request

```
$scope.getSearcHistory = function(){
     console.log($localStorage.token);
     console.log( $rootScope.getCurrentUser());
    $http({
        url: baseUrl+'userSearches/2',
        method : 'GET',
        headers: {
            'key': '1234424252'
        }
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.searches = data;
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log(status);
    });
}
```

This is my NodeJS Contoller

```
this.router.use(function(req, res, next){
        console.log(req.headers);
        var bearerToken;
        var bearerHeader = req.headers.authorization;
        console.log(bearerHeader)
        if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
            var bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
            bearerToken = bearer[1];
            req.token = bearerToken;
            next();
        } else {
            res.send(403).json({"Authorization": "Not allowed"});
        }
    });
```

Here is my Node console, see there is no header which i need --

```
{ 
host: 'localhost:8080',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'access-control-request-method': 'GET',
origin: 'http://localhost:440',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
'access-control-request-headers': 'authorization,key',
accept: '*/*',
referer: 'http://localhost:440/vokal/'}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code it seems that you should not have any problems. What you are doing in angular should ideally give you your custom header

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'test',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        "X-Test-Header": 'true'
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    if (response.data == 'ok') {
        // success
    } else {
        // failed
    }
});
```

Could you check your console once whether or not you are getting the header.

If even this does not work then maybe you need to set your node to allow all headers

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
};
```

and configure it in your app

```
app.configure(function () {
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(allowCrossDomain);
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});
```

All of this just handles whether or not a custom header can be sent or not. If you are working with auth tokens you need to set it properly in your $http in angular so that it can be sent everytime a request is made. For that you might want to include

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['x-access-token'] = jwt
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that when I am getting the header in Express app check my question `access-control-request-headers: 'authorization,key'` But I req.headers.authorization and req.headers.key both are undefined.  I mean How to access the value ?

Comment: If you do a print on req.headers then what value do you get?

Comment: last code block in my question is the `console.log(req.headers`)

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed that. Did you try copying the same headers which I have given. I tried the same thing but I wasn't able to reproduce this error. Also, try updating your `authorization` as it is case sensitive.